# Windows 7 auto shutdown after certain period of inactivity

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

Is there any solution for auto shutting down Win 7 PC? Many colleagues in our company leave their desktops turned on after leaving job, so we would like to shut them down after certain period of inactivity (let say, after 30 - 60 minutes of being idle)?

Comment: Are the machines on a domain?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same domain

Comment: easiest way is to push out a gpo to disable all standby states (sleep/hibernate) reference: https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/369-preventing-computer-from-going-into-sleep-mode

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by creating a scheduled task:

[Windows forums: Shutdown after idle](https://www.windows10forums.com/articles/shutdown-after-pc-has-been-idle.41/)

You will have to add this scheduled task to each computer. This article is for Windows 10, but the Windows 7 task scheduler should contain all the same functions.